# Video chat in android

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat, sipdroid

**What i am doing:**

I am building an android application for 1 to 1 video chatting and i need help here

**What i did:**

1) I came across [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android), i tried my best to understand and implement it and i really coudn't get it working

2) I researched about [Sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/), i cant understand it either

**What i want:**

I am in need of either

1) A simple library, with good documentation to implement video chat.

2) An excellent tutorial for implementing video chat in android.

Please guide me

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android . It contains step by step instruction of what should be done. You can also check QB Android SDK http://sdk.quickblox.com/android/

Comment: @Darya i get 'NoClassDefFoundError' at com.quickblox.module.chat.smack.SmackAndroid!!?

Comment: @Darya ok problem solved. I need to ckeck 'Order and export' in java build path. That was very helpful thanks